# Jboss 4 to wildfly-8 migration delayed http listener start

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly-8

I am trying to move an web-application from jboss-4.2.3 to wildfly-8.1.0.
The application has an ear deployment. Inside ear(XXX.ear),it has a war(YYY.ear) and sar(ZZZ.sar).
When ear is deployed, the war and sar deployment starts. The war takes around 30s to deploy, whereas sar takes around 5mins to deployed. My use-case is that the web-application UI should not be shown till both the modules are deployed.
I have even tried adding the below configuration in **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
< sub-deployment name="YYY.war">
      < dependencies>
         < module name="com.aryaka.nos" export="true"/>
            < module name="deployment.XXX.ear" />
            < module name="deployment.XXX.ear.ZZZ.sar" />
        < /dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```

I am suspecting that the wildfly has changed the way the http service starts.Below is the excerpt of the old and new logs.
In jboss-4.2.3 the http service used to start after both the war and ear had been deployed.

`2014-08-27 09:18:11,545 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.JBossWeb] Saw org.jboss.system.server.started notification, starting connectors
2014-08-27 09:18:11,550 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-8080`

But in wildfly, the http listener starts even before the war and ear has been deployed (parallely deployed).

`2014-08-27 15:04:25,484 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0.0.1:8080`

Is there any other configuration such that the http service starts after the deployment?